# Как мне отсортировать первую половину массива по парным индексам?

Tags: c++, c

Есть массив из 16 элементов. Нужно отсортировать первую половину массива по парным индексам.

Например есть массив arr = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], тогда отсортированный по первой половине и парным индексам массив будет выглядеть так arr = [4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1]

Ниже приведен код, который при выводе выдает массив arr = [5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1].

Подскажите где у меня ошибка в коде.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {

int const SIZE = 24;


int mas[SIZE];

srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    mas[i] = rand() % 100;


}
int write;
for (int i = 0; i < (SIZE / 2) - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (SIZE/2) - i - 2; j++) {
        if (mas[j] > mas[j + 1]) {
            write= mas[i];
            mas[i + 1] = write;
            

        
        }
    
    
    }


}
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    cout << mas[i] <<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можете отредактировать свой вопрос, чтобы стало более понятней, что вам нужно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вам нужно было, то вот пример кода:

```cpp
int size_2 = SIZE / 2;
int zapus;
//В оригинальном алгоритме сортировки мы отступает от правой границы на 1
//т.к. знаем, что там находится уже самое бОльшое число. Но в нашем случае
//мы пропускаем 2 числа. Самое бОльшое и с индексом не кратным двум.
for (int i = 0; i < size_2 - 1; i += 2) {
    //Вместо проверки на кратность j проходим просто по четным числам
    for (int j = 0; j < size_2 - i - 2; j += 2) {
        //Сравниваем элемент под индексом j с элементом через 1.
        //то есть с индексом j + 2
        if (mas[j] > mas[j + 2]) {
            zapus = mas[j];
            mas[j] = mas[j + 2];
            mas[j + 2] = zapus;
        }
    }
}
```

Алгоритм производит сортировку пузырьком на промежутке от [0, SIZE / 2] сравнивая элемент с другим через другой.

Comment: Спасибо а то я уже с индексом начал думать как делать ищо хуже б зделал!!!